# Default Primary Key Index or User created Index, which will have priority in execution in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, database-indexes

You have primary key (Oracle creates default index on a primary key called B tree index) as well as user created index on the same table then which index will fire ?

Comment: Why would you create a duplicate index?  The Oracle optimizer will choose whichever index it calculates to be best for the query.

Comment: When Oracle Query optimizer builds an executtion plan it will choose one, both or no indexes depending on query, data cardinality, etc. Your question can not be answered without a query.

Comment: By definition, the two indexes must have a different ordered set of columns.  You can't have a completely duplicate index.  The optimizer will use whichever index it expects to be more efficient or no index if it expects a full table scan to be more efficient.